# Monitoring Lock Unlock Screen - Shell Script

Tags: ubuntu, locking, screen

I made script to monitor how long the functionary is actually using the PC, put it to lock the screen after 2 minutes of inactivity.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash   
day=$(date +"%d-%m-%Y")    
dbus-monitor --session "type='signal',interface='org.gnome.ScreenSaver',member='ActiveChanged'" | while read line ; do

if [ x"$(echo "$line" | grep 'boolean true')" != x ] ; 
then
echo "lock#$(date +%R)" >> /home/user/.worklog/work.$day
fi

if [ x"$(echo "$line" | grep 'boolean false')" != x ] ; 
then
echo "unlock#$(date +%R)" >> /home/user/.worklog/work.$day
fi
done
```

My problem is:

When i monitoring Ubuntu 12.04 the output is:

```
lock#10:56
unlock#10:56
lock#11:00
unlock#11:32
lock#11:44
unlock#13:01
lock#13:10
```

but, when i monitoring Ubuntu 12.10 the output is:

```
unlock#08:24
lock#08:45
unlock#08:45
lock#08:55
lock#09:13
unlock#09:13
unlock#09:13
lock#10:38
lock#10:39
unlock#10:39
unlock#10:39
lock#10:52
unlock#10:52
lock#11:03
```

Anyone have any idea how to fix?

Comment: @suspectus - Review of edits is automatically handled by the community - no need to involve moderators.